# Update Type in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Need assistance to on the below query in excel, This is the senarior

```
description             version   type    Expected output
1-Upgrade Kit            165737    A                  B
7668A CPU UPGRADE        165737    B                  B
ASSY,PCB,P2MB,VME,       165737    B                  B
UPGRADE,EPROM            165737    B                  B
KIT,7668A CPU UPGRADE     165738    B                 B
1-Upgrade Kit             165738    A                 B
1-Upgrade Kit            165739     A                 C
KIT,7668A CPU UPGRADE     165739    C                 C
KIT,7668A CPU UPGRADE    165739     C                 C
```

as you see the version number to be same for first four lines,but the type has change when the description has string "upgrade kit".can we fetch type from other lines when we have same version and description as "upgrade kit"

Comment: Hi Tharun, welcome to SO. It is difficult to understand what you're trying to do. Could you edit and be more accurate? Do you mean you want to group the records by same `version` column?

Comment: I want to replace the type when count of version is more then 1 and description reads"Upgrade kit" i want to change the type value same as other example: first four lines have same version numbers but type has changed when upgrade kit is the description.same way version number "165739" has three lines but type has change when decription reads as "upgrade kit", in that instance i want to consider the type from other lines

Comment: Sorry, this must be me who cannot understand this logic. Are you able to write an algorithm down for this? If so, kindly edit your **original question*** with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well your problem, this should do the trick.

I go through all 'description', when it finds "Upgrade Kit", it then looks for the same version number and change the type accordingly.

```
Sub ChangeVersion()

Dim rCell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim DescriptRng As Range
Set DescriptRng = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    For Each rCell In DescriptRng

        If rCell = "1-Upgrade Kit" Then
            For i = 2 To LastRow
                If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(rCell.Row, 2) And Cells(i, 1) <> "1-Upgrade Kit" Then
                Cells(rCell.Row, 3) = Cells(i, 3)
                End If
            Next i
        End If

    Next rCell

End Sub
```

Tell me if it's fine for you.